# Set Access-Control-Allow-Origin in nginx using wildcard domain

Tags: security, nginx, http-headers

With `nginx` can I specify `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` using a wildcard like `*.mydomain.com`?

Would it look like:

```
add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *.mydomain.com;
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You sure can.  I use the following directive to support some of our cross domain fonts:

```
  add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
```

Comment: No I don't want wildcard for everything, but only anything.mydomain.com. I have a SaaS and each signup get's their own subdomain (user.mydomain.com). Also, I am testing and put `add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin http://google.com;` for testing, and assumed requests would fail, but surprisingly they still work. Any idea why? They should fail right?

Comment: Ah, I understand.  Yes, you can use globs, though I can't say for certain why requests aren't failing like they should.  The very long answer on how to use Access-Control is here: http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/WD-access-control-20080912/

Comment: Actually further research, shows that `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` only supports `*` and a full host, i.e. wildcard domains are **NOT** supported. However still not sure why requests are working when I set: `add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin https://google.com;`

Comment: Ah, seems I learned something as well then!

Answer (score 11):

you have to do it with an if condition

```
location /  {
  set $cors "";
  if ($http_origin ~* (\.mydomain\.com|\.myseconddomain\.com)$) {
      set $cors "true";
  }

  proxy_pass http://backend:10005/apathifyouwantso/;

  if ($cors = "true") {
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' "$http_origin";
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT';
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'User-Agent,Keep-Alive,Content-Type';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Setting "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" based on conditions in nginx is very dangerous and you should be careful.
The answer above is opening a security vulnerability.

```
if ($http_origin ~* (\.mydomain\.com|\.myseconddomain\.com))
```

This line will match something.mydomain.com and also something.mydomain.com.anyotherdomain.com (A domain anyone can create)

Doing this, will allow the following scenario:

1. A banner makes users open something.mydomain.com.anyotherdomain.com
2. Which makes requests to your site using `fetch`.
3. Fetch, can include credentials, which means your user cookies.
4. So the attacker can make requests to your server authenticated as that user. (Ex: send messages, emails, etc)

And all of that, because the regular expression is missing one '$' at the end.

```
if ($http_origin ~* (\.mydomain\.com|\.myseconddomain\.com)$)
```

Thats not the only way you can make that particular regexp bad, thats why I am explaining the problem, rather than just adding $ in the previous answer

Comment: should this be a comment to [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/829402/) rather than an answer to this post?

Comment: @mforsetti sadly it's too long for a comment, but he could incorporate the other answer inside his to make it a complete answer.

Comment: @yagmoth555 yeah, I guess that's also possible; remembering that you need 50 reps to make a comment.

Comment: I have 1 rep point, so I can't edit the answer. Perhaps someone else will